# Partially de-serialization JSON to get required attributes only

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I get big response in JSON formate, I need only 2 strings from that, Here it my JSON file in which I reduced for better read

```
{
  "cdn_url": "https://f.vimeocdn.com",
  "vimeo_api_url": "api.vimeo.com",
  "request": {
    "files": {
      "progressive": [
        {
          "profile": 164,
          "width": 622,
          "mime": "video/mp4",
          "fps": 25,
          "url": "1047326445.mp4",
          "cdn": "akamai_interconnect",
          "quality": "360p",
          "id": 1047326445,
          "origin": "gcs",
          "height": 360
        },
        {
          "profile": 165,
          "width": 932,
          "mime": "video/mp4",
          "fps": 25,
          "url": "1047326437.mp4",
          "cdn": "akamai_interconnect",
          "quality": "540p",
          "id": 1047326437,
          "origin": "gcs",
          "height": 540
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  "video": {
    "version": {
      "current": null,
      "available": null
    },
    "height": 540,
    "duration": 401,
    "thumbs": {
      "640": "712851375_640.jpg",
      "960": "712851375_960.jpg",
      "base": "712851375"
    },
    "id": 279550927,
    "default_to_hd": 0,
    "url": null,
    "privacy": "disable",
    "unlisted_hash": null
  }
}
```

I removed lots of objects from it for better read. 
i want "url": "1047326445.mp4", from "progressive array and string from "640" variable which is in video object.

```
    protected void btnclick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string normalURL = "279550927";
        string urlJSONcall = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/" + normalURL + "/config";

        string json = null;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlJSONcall);
        HttpWebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            if ((responseStream != null) && responseStream.CanRead)
            {
                using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    LBresponse.Text = json;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                response.Close();
            }
        }

        var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

    }
}
```

because of nested objects its getting confusing for me to resolve it.

i dont know what to do next,

Comment: Using JSON.Net -Newtonsoft you can query the json. Check https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJson.htm or https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm.

Comment: thanks for giving me that link!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i GOT DESIRE RESULT THROUGH THIS,

```
        string json = null;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlJSONcall);
        HttpWebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            if ((responseStream != null) && responseStream.CanRead)
            {
                using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    json = reader.ReadToEnd();

                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                response.Close();
            }
        }

        var datao = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        //LBresponse.Text = data.ToString();
        string urll = (string)datao["request"]["files"]["progressive"][0]["url"];

        string thumbnailImage = (string)datao["video"]["thumbs"]["640"];
        LBresponse.Text = urll.ToString();
        lbltumb.Text = thumbnailImage.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked with me:

```
protected void btnclick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string normalURL = "279550927";
        string urlJSONcall = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/" + normalURL + "/config";
        using (var w = new WebClient())
        {
            var json_data = string.Empty;
            // attempt to download JSON data as a string
            try
            {
                json_data = w.DownloadString(urlJSONcall).Replace("\"640\"", "\"_640\"");;
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
            // if string with JSON data is not empty, deserialize it to class and return its instance 
            var mainObject = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data) ? Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json_data) : null;

            string cdn_url = mainObject?.cdn_url;
            string vimeo_api_url = mainObject?.vimeo_api_url;
            string _640 = mainObject?.video?.thumbs?._640;
            var Prgs = mainObject?.request?.files?.progressive;
            foreach (var progressive in Prgs)
            {
                string URL = progressive.url;
            }
        }
    }
```

But if you care about the types returned you can use this solution:
Step 1:

```
protected void btnclick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string normalURL = "279550927";
        string urlJSONcall = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/" + normalURL + "/config";
        using (var w = new WebClient())
        {
            var json_data = string.Empty;
            // attempt to download JSON data as a string
            try
            {
                json_data = w.DownloadString(urlJSONcall).Replace("\"640\"", "\"_640\"");;
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
            // if string with JSON data is not empty, deserialize it to class and return its instance 
            MainObject mainObject = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data) ? Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainObject>(json_data) : null;

            string cdn_url = mainObject?.cdn_url;
            string vimeo_api_url = mainObject?.vimeo_api_url;
            string _640 = mainObject?.video?.thumbs?._640;
            var Prgs = mainObject?.request?.files?.progressive;
            foreach (Progressive progressive in Prgs)
            {
                string URL = progressive.url;
            }
        }
    }
```

Step2: Add these classes to navigate through the properties

```
   public class MainObject
{
    public string cdn_url { get; set; }
    public string vimeo_api_url { get; set; }
    public Request request { get; set; }
    public Video video { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public Files files { get; set; }
}

public class Files
{
    public Progressive[] progressive { get; set; }
}

public class Progressive
{
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Video
{
    public Thumbs thumbs { get; set; }
}
public class Thumbs
{
    public string _640 { get; set; }
}
```